# Creating collection of objects obtained via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, collections, casting

Lets say I got some `Object o` and `o instanceof XXX == true`. I now want to create (at runtime) ArrayList of type XXX like that `ArrayList<XXX>()`. Is there any way to do that? I currently create just `ArrayList<Object>` but it's not enough.

Answer (score 2):

> When runtime inspecting a parameterizable type itself, like java.util.List, there is no way of knowing what type is has been parameterized to. This makes sense since the type can be parameterized to all kinds of types in the same application. But, when you inspect the method or field that declares the use of a parameterized type, you can see at runtime what type the paramerizable type was parameterized to.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html

---

Unfortunately you can't get the parameterized type in runtime. Generics was conceived to provide compile-type safety.
Hope the link above helps =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do that. Generics are only meant to give you compile-time type safety.

Comment: So basically if I create classes at run time I can't put them in a collection of type that I don't know at compile time? That's a shame :<

Comment: Not using generics. I guess, if you have a limited amount of type possibilities, a work around would be to define some kind of wrapper that will take in argument the type of your class, and return the appropriate collection.

Comment: Well it would still be a bad work around though, I'd have modify the wrapper every time after adding a new class and add an if.